# How to generate a response in a long running synchronous request in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, synchronous

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this using Rails, though it is probably cause I don't know the proper term for it.

I basically want to do this:

```
def my_action
    sleep 1

    # output something in the request, but keep it open
    print '{"progress":15}'

    sleep 3

    # output something else, keep it open
    print '{"progress":65}'

    sleep 1

    # append some more, and close the request
    print '{"sucess":true}'
end
```

However I can't figure out how to do this. I basically want to replicate a slow internet connection.

I need to do this because I am scraping websites, which takes time, where I am 'sleeping' above.

**Update**
I'm reading this using iOS, so I don't want a websocket server, I think.

Comment: The term you're probably after is "flushing". You probably want it to flush output after each print(). There's a little info about Rails 3.1 auto-flushing here http://yehudakatz.com/2010/09/07/automatic-flushing-the-rails-3-1-plan/ though not directly related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is exactly what you're looking for:

[Infinite streaming JSON from Rails 3.1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyRjFolajfE)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do some reading around HTML5 WebSockets (there are backwards compatible hacks for older browsers) which let you push data to the client from the server.

Rails has a number of ways to implement a WebSockets server.  This question gives some of the options [Best Ruby on Rails WebSocket tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767268/best-ruby-on-rails-websocket-tool)

Answer (score 0):

If that would work on the server-side, how would you handle it on the client-side?
HTTP requests normally can just have one response (which may be chunked when using streaming, which wouldn't work in your case I think).

I guess you would either have to look into websockets or make separate requests for each step.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest in most modern browsers will periodically fire an onreadystatechange event when new data arrives, so it's possible in a browser. But in any event, this is a scraper, nota browser, so it's straightforward network programming to keep pulling from the incoming buffer.

Comment: I'm reading it using iOS, so it is fairly simple to read it at each step.